# Multiple SSL Namebased Multiple Virtual host on one ip address and Port

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, sni, website-hosting

I want to configure ssl on same ip and port using SNI or can be different port but i am unable to instruct apache to deliver the ssl certificate of the domain requested.

It delivers the default sites certificate. I am unable to debug the issue.

I access logs it shows the default domain name however request is of other domain..

E.g i ask site1.com then site1.com opens and it delivers site1.com, however if i ask site2.con it delivers ssl of site1.com and site2.com is redirected to site1.com

If i add 
      domainname:443 
instead of 
      *:443 
then browser give 241 redirect error and it is as follows

> Misdirected Request The client needs a new connection for this request
>   as the requested host name does not match the Server Name Indication
>   (SNI) in use for this connection.

I am listening on port 80 and 443 in /etc/apache2/ports.conf
i have installed ssl mod using 
      apt-get install libapache2-mod-ssl
      a2enmod ssl

i am using ubuntu server bionic (18) with latest apache2 version and openssl

i have concerned multiple sources however following these links did not resolved my problem

[Digicert.com](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm)

[memset.com](https://www.memset.com/docs/memset-guides/hosting-multiple-ssl-sites-single-ip/)

[digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04)

[apache.org](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI)

[Techrepublic](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/configure-apache-to-support-multiple-ssl-sites-on-a-single-ip-address/)

[Tech-stuff.net](https://stuff-things.net/2016/11/16/apache-sni/)

```
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    <VirtualHost *:443>

            ServerAdmin admin@site1.com
            ServerName site1.com/
            ServerAlias www.site1.com/

            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site1.com/certificate.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site1.com/private.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site1.com/ca_bundle.crt



            DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com/public_html

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>




<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName site1.com

    ServerAlias www.site1.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com/public_html

    Redirect permanent / https://site1.com/

</VirtualHost>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    <VirtualHost *:443>

            ServerAdmin admin@site2.com
            ServerName site2.com/

            ServerAlias www.site2.com/

            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site2.com/certificate.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site2.com/private.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site2.com/ca_bundle.crt



            DocumentRoot /var/www/site2.com/public_html

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>


< VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName site2.com

    ServerAlias www.site2.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2.com/public_html

    Redirect permanent / https://site2.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to configure properly your apache server to have multiple SSL Virtual Hosts using the same public ip address you should follow these steps:

Edit your **httpd.conf** or **apache2.conf** file and check if you have the entries bellow:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualhost *:443
```

Then for all your virtual hosts, replace

```
<VirtualHost *:80> with <VirtualHost YOUR_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP:80>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:443> with <VirtualHost YOUR_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP:443>
```

Restart apache and you should be good to go!

Be sure that there is no other entry or config file with a `<VirtualHost *:443>` definition. All definitions should container the actual server ip address, otherwise you'll have exactly the same issue.

Comment: I have tried. I even tried with domain name instead of *. It delivers default certificate.

Comment: You have a configuration issue somewhere or a virtual host which is defined with *:443 and other with ip address and so on... It should work since it works just fine on my CentOS 7.x server with httpd. In `<VirtualHost>` section the definition is `ip:port`, not `domain:port`

Comment: Alternatively, replace `NameVirtualHost *:80` and `NameVirtualHost *:443` with `NameVirtualHost public_IP:80` respectively `NameVirtualHost public_IP:443` and restart httpd/apache2 service

Comment: It's really hard to say at this point without being able to check the config and see what is going on there, on your server... Sorry I can't help you more... It's definetely a config issue since as I was saying, it works just fine on my server

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.    I was doing it wrong i guess. I shifted all config in one .conf file with sequence  of all port 80 and then port 443 respectively. And it works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it works. As I was saying, there was some issue with your config... You could vote the answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

In VirtualHost domain_name:443 the IP of domain_name is matched with the source IP address of the incoming request.
This is important to understand as the IP address of incoming request is different when the Apache server is standalone or behind a proxy server !
Behind a proxy server the IP address is the IP address of origin server.